# Time overflow over 2 days, determining if time is now part of day 1 or 2

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have the following scenario from data in a database:

```
Current logic
Monday    08:00 - 17:00
Tuesday   08:00 - 15:00
Tuesday   17:00 - 23:00
Wednesday 08:00 - 03:00 (overflow next day)
Thursday  08:00 - 03:00 (overflow next day)
Friday    09:00 - 11:00

public class WorkTimeFrameModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the raw value of the day of the week enum.
    /// </summary>
    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the start of the time frame as a TimeSpan.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the end of the time frame as a TimeSpan.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the enum value of the DayOfWeek property.
    /// </summary>
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeekEnum
    {
        get { return (DayOfWeek)DayOfWeek; }
        set { DayOfWeek = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

Currently I wrote code that can determine an overflow if the day does not matter and it works flawlessly:

```
    internal bool IsWithinWorkingTimes(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var startDate = dateTime.Date;
        var endDate = dateTime.Date;

        //Times with overflows that could be variable
        var start = new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00);
        var end = new TimeSpan(03, 00, 00);

        //var start = new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00);
        //var end = new TimeSpan(17, 00, 00);


        startDate = startDate.Date + start;
        endDate = endDate.Date + end;

        if (start > end)
        {
            return dateTime > startDate || dateTime < endDate;
        }

        return dateTime >= startDate && dateTime <= endDate;
    }
```

But now for specific days, how do I determine if the current time is in the second day or in the first day, like above:

1. Lets say its now Thursday 01:00 in the morning and the data is Wednesday 08:00 - 03:00
2. or Lets say its now Wednesday 15:00 in the afternoon and the data is Wednesday 08:00 - 03:00

I know this scenario is actually a design flaw and you should prohibit a user to go past 00:00, but unfortunately the design cannot be altered because we do not manage the frontend, so i am fixing it now in an api on code we can manage at this stage.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the scenario. Your sample data includes "(overflow next day)" but that doesn't seem to be modeled anywhere, and you haven't explained it in terms of requirements. Please add more explanation.

Comment: What is `ApplicationSettings`?

Comment: So it is `WorkTimeFrameModel`?

Comment: No this is another model that does not include specific dates or days. Its contains a start and end time in string format.

Comment: And how are you using `WorkTimeFrameModel` in your code?

Comment: I get it, its a bit confusing I am editing it, forget the work WorkTimeFrameModel  in the code I have, I just tested it for that scenario.

Comment: You are using a 12 hours time format without AM/PM. How can you determine if its morning or afternoon?

Comment: Don't use EndTime, use Duration.  Now it is no longer ambiguous for days.

Comment: Switching to duration doesn't necessarily help for this scenario.  For example, if you had a shift starting on Tuesday at 23:00 that goes overnight, it still includes times on Wednesday morning. It doesn't matter if you define it as ending at 07:00 or as being 8 hours, you still have to take the change of the day-of-week into consideration.

Comment: FWIW - I think the scenario of a schedule of hours by day-of-week with overnights is extremely common.  I think the question could have been asked a bit clearer, but it's still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a weekly schedule of times can apply to a broad variety of situations, so I'll expand from the code in the question a bit.  For clarity, I'm going to use [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.dateonly) and [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timeonly), so .NET 6 or newer will be required. Feel free to adapt from this implementation as needed.

Let's call the table of times a `Schedule`, and each row in it a `ScheduleItem`.  At a high level, the API looks like this:

```cs
public class Schedule : List<ScheduleItem>
{
    public bool IsScheduled(DateTime dateTime);
}

public class ScheduleItem
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; }
    public TimeOnly StartTime { get; }
    public TimeOnly EndTime { get; }

    public ScheduleItem(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, TimeOnly startTime, TimeOnly endTime);
}
```

This design allows us to add items to a schedule, then check if any given `DateTime` is scheduled or not.

Here's the implementation.  See code comments for details.

```cs
public class Schedule : List<ScheduleItem>
{
    // Returns true if the provided DateTime matches any of the items in this schedule.
    public bool IsScheduled(DateTime dateTime) => this.Any(item => item.IsScheduled(dateTime));
}

public class ScheduleItem
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; }
    public TimeOnly StartTime { get; }
    public TimeOnly EndTime { get; }
    
    public ScheduleItem(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, TimeOnly startTime, TimeOnly endTime)
    {
        DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }
    
    // Returns true if the provided DateTime matches this schedule item.
    internal bool IsScheduled(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        // Get the range of DateTimes that apply for the date of the provided DateTime.
        var date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime);
        var range = GetApplicableRange(date);
        
        // See if the provided DateTime falls into that range.
        // NOTE: The range is a half-open interval [Start, End).
        // The start is inclusive, but the end is exclusive.
        return dateTime >= range.Start && dateTime < range.End;
    }
    
    // Returns a DateTime range that is applicable for the given date, for this schedule item.
    private (DateTime Start, DateTime End) GetApplicableRange(DateOnly date)
    {
        // Use this schedule item if it matches the provided date.
        if (DayOfWeek == date.DayOfWeek)
        {
            return GetRange(date, StartTime, EndTime);
        }
        
        // Also use this schedule item if it matches the previous date,
        // but only when inverted because that means the end time will be on the provided date.
        var previousDate = date.AddDays(-1);
        if (DayOfWeek == previousDate.DayOfWeek && StartTime > EndTime)
        {
            return GetRange(previousDate, StartTime, EndTime);
        }
    
        // This schedule item is not applicable to the provided date.
        // Return a zero-duration range to prevent any match.
        return (DateTime.MaxValue, DateTime.MaxValue);
    }

    // Returns a range of DateTime values from the provided parameters.
    private static (DateTime Start, DateTime End) GetRange(DateOnly date, TimeOnly startTime, TimeOnly endTime)
    {
        // The start time is always on the date given.
        var startDateTime = date.ToDateTime(startTime);
        
        // The end time might be on the date given, or on the following day.
        var endDateTime = startTime < endTime
            ? date.ToDateTime(endTime)
            : date.AddDays(1).ToDateTime(endTime);

        return (startDateTime, endDateTime);
    }
}
```

Here's a usage example with various test cases. I used the list provided in the question, and added one more to cover an edge case.

```cs
var schedule = new Schedule
{
    new(DayOfWeek.Monday, new TimeOnly(8, 0), new TimeOnly(17, 0)),
    new(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeOnly(8, 0), new TimeOnly(15, 0)),
    new(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new TimeOnly(17, 0), new TimeOnly(23, 0)),
    new(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new TimeOnly(8, 0), new TimeOnly(3, 0)),
    new(DayOfWeek.Thursday, new TimeOnly(8, 0), new TimeOnly(3, 0)),
    new(DayOfWeek.Friday, new TimeOnly(9, 0), new TimeOnly(11, 0)),
    new(DayOfWeek.Friday, new TimeOnly(23, 0), new TimeOnly(6, 0)),
};

Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 1, 8, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 1, 17, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 1, 19, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 2, 14, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 2, 15, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 2, 16, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 2, 17, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 3, 23, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 4, 2, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 5, 2, 0, 0), true);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 5, 4, 0, 0), false);
Test(new DateTime(2023, 5, 6, 4, 0, 0), true);

void Test(DateTime dateTime, bool expectation)
{
    var scheduled = schedule.IsScheduled(dateTime);
    var correct = scheduled == expectation;
    Console.WriteLine($"{dateTime:dddd HH:mm} - {(scheduled ? "scheduled" : "not scheduled")} ({(correct ? "correct" : "incorrect")})");
}
```

Results:

```
Monday 02:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Monday 08:00 - scheduled (correct)
Monday 12:00 - scheduled (correct)
Monday 17:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Monday 19:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Tuesday 14:00 - scheduled (correct)
Tuesday 15:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Tuesday 16:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Tuesday 17:00 - scheduled (correct)
Wednesday 23:00 - scheduled (correct)
Thursday 00:00 - scheduled (correct)
Thursday 02:00 - scheduled (correct)
Thursday 03:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Friday 02:00 - scheduled (correct)
Friday 04:00 - not scheduled (correct)
Saturday 04:00 - scheduled (correct)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (and more). I thank you so much. Apperently it seems that my question was difficult to understand, but clearly you did. I think that its because I overexplained it. I tried it myself and everytime I am just at the point when I think I did it and then some other scenario again does not work. I think this post will make alot of people happy in the future and you contributed to it. Thanks for all that contributed even if my question was not that clear

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly (and I find it a little hard to do so), you should be able to just compare the Hour:Minute of `dateTime` with the Hour:Minute of `end` (or `start`, if you switch your logic around).

If the end is greater than now, you must be in the second day.

These checks obviously only work as intended after you checked that you are *in* the working hours.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Won't work that way. Take "Monday, 20h -> 4h" and DateTime says it's Monday, 14h. That's > end but outside the frame.

Comment: @Fildor as you can see, I noted this in the third paragraph of my answer and the question already contains the code necessary to do the check.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. **If** you know you are in the frame and current day == day then it's day 1, else it's day 2. Start and end are irrelevant at that time. Or **I** am missing something? But then again, the question is confusing to begin with.

Comment: @Fildor what do you mean by "current day == day"? There is only one **Date**Time given and the data you are comparing it against only contains information about time. Otherwise what would be the difficulty in comparing two date values.

Comment: Question specifies one DayOfWeek and two TimeSpan.